# Correct way to return a list of unique keys from Object

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, lodash

I have this code

```
discounts = { 'N18-AB0': 10,
  'N18-AB2': 10,
  'N18-BL2': 10,
  'N22-WHBL0': 10,
  'N22-WHBL1': 10,
  'N22-WHBL2': 10,
  'N22-WHBL3': 10,
  'N50P-CT2': 10,
  'N50P-CT4': 10,
  'SA61-MBL': 10,
  'SA61-MGR': 10,
  'SA61-MHE': 10,
  'SA61-MMB': 10,
  'SA61-MNA': 10,
  'SA61-MPL': 10 }
```

then I am using `lowdash` to extract the keys values

```
specials = (req, res, next) ->
  Promise.props
    discounts: discounts
  .then (result) ->
    StyleIds = []
    if result.discounts isnt null
      discounts = result.discounts
      StyleIds = _.forOwn discounts, (value, key) ->
        styleId = key.split(/-/)[0]
        styleId
```

how do i return an array of styleIds so that i get unique values such as `'N18', 'N22', 'N50P', 'SA61']`

any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can start by **[lazy evaluating](https://lodash.com/docs#_)** the `discounts` object by using **[`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map)** and **[`_.uniq`](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq)**.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/68e2NrQeFM7NYtP5tOup?p=preview)**

```
var result = _(discounts)
  .map(function(value, key) {
    return key.split('-')[0];
  })
  .uniq()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
var discounts = { 'N18-AB0': 10,
  'N18-AB2': 10,
  'N18-BL2': 10,
  'N22-WHBL0': 10,
  'N22-WHBL1': 10,
  'N22-WHBL2': 10,
  'N22-WHBL3': 10,
  'N50P-CT2': 10,
  'N50P-CT4': 10,
  'SA61-MBL': 10,
  'SA61-MGR': 10,
  'SA61-MHE': 10,
  'SA61-MMB': 10,
  'SA61-MNA': 10,
  'SA61-MPL': 10 };

Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
   var u = {}, a = [];
   for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
      if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
         continue;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
      u[this[i]] = 1;
   }
   return a;
}
/* 1. Get keys array
 * 2. Split keys and get value before -
 * 3. Return unique values in an array. */
console.log(Object.keys(discounts).map(function(item){ return item.split("-")[0]}).getUnique());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with CoffeeScript, but here is an example using lodash in Javascript

```
function getUniqueStyleIds(obj) {
    return _.chain(obj)
        .keys()
        .map(function(key) { return key.split('-')[0]; })
        .uniq()
        .value();
}
```

Comment: snap, i just got it, before i saw your answer, thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

i got it like this:

```
specials = (req, res, next) ->
  Promise.props
    discounts: discounts
  .then (result) ->
    if result.discounts isnt null
      discounts = result.discounts
      styles = _(result.discounts)
        .keys()
        .flatten()
        .map( (c) -> c.split(/-/)[0] )
        .unique()
        .value()
```

then styles returns `[ 'N18', 'N22', 'N50P', 'SA61' ]`